# Put a constraint on defcustom with variable type

Tags: defcustom

I have a `defcustom` with `:type` `variable`, 
and I would like to constrain the variable name to comply to a pattern.

How would I do that?

for instance let say I want the custom to only accept a variable name starting with some prefix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use type `variable`. Use type **`restricted-sexp`**.

The predicate checks for a `symbolp` that is `boundp` (i.e., a variable) and whose `symbol-name` is matched by your chosen prefix.

See the Elisp manual, node [Composite Types](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Composite-Types.html).

Comment: Thanks Drew. I tried your solution, but for a strange reason the validating function is being called with nil except for the initial value. 
Besides the `set` handler is also called!
Any idea why?

Comment: Here is the code in question: https://gist.github.com/AdrieanKhisbe/81dbd538b6b8cca0b2dadd33ac24a6ed

Comment: Looks like you accidentally used `fboundp' in one place, instead of `boundp'.

Comment: And you spot it right! Thanks a lot @Drew! :)